# Two ways to startActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

Please explain me? what's difference when I start activity:

```
startActivity(Intent(this@someContext, SomeActivity::class.java))
```

and, when I start:

```
startActivity(SomeActivity.getIntent(this@someContext)
```

???

Comment: Are you sure that the static function `getIntent(Context)` exists within the `Activity`? I can't really find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two code snippets you provided are different ways to start an activity in Android using intents. Let's break down each one:

1. `startActivity(Intent(this@someContext, SomeActivity::class.java))`:
   In this case, you are creating an explicit intent using the Intent class. You pass the current context `(this@someContext)` and the target activity (`SomeActivity::class.java`) as parameters to the intent constructor. When you call `startActivity()` with this intent, it will start the SomeActivity directly.
2. `startActivity(SomeActivity.getIntent(this@someContext))`:
   This snippet suggests that the SomeActivity class has a static method `getIntent()` defined. This method is likely implemented within the SomeActivity class and returns an intent specific to that activity. By calling `SomeActivity.getIntent(this@someContext)`, you are obtaining an intent instance tailored to start SomeActivity. Then, you use startActivity() with that intent to start the activity.

The main difference between the two approaches lies in how the intent is created. In the first approach, you create the intent explicitly, specifying the target activity using its class. In the second approach, you rely on a static method (`getIntent()`) defined within the activity class to provide the intent instance.

The second approach can be useful when the activity itself needs to configure the intent or pass additional data to itself. It encapsulates the logic for creating the intent within the activity class, making it more modular and easier to manage.

Ultimately, both approaches achieve the same goal of starting an activity using an intent, but the second approach offers more flexibility and allows for better organization of the code.

Comment: Stop using ChatGPT bro - `Activity.getIntent(Context)` simply does not exist.

Comment: @sweak This is from real big project. And Maulik Togadiya explained it very clearly. I use ChatGPT very rear, bro

Comment: @Maulik Togadiya you are absolutely  true. I didn't notice this fun right away. Thank you so much!

Comment: @sweak I used Chat GPT because It helps and may explained very well then if i do.Also it is clearly mentioned that Activity.getIntent(Context) is not predefined method it will be created by us as  as SomeActivity.getIntent(this@someContext)

Comment: If it is an internal function in your own system then you should consider creating a StackOverflow Team - as far as I know it would suit your case very well, because there is noone else that would be able to answer your question than you and people that are working on that system. Second of all - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1